# Websockets working only in localhost and not in staging or production server

Tags: php, sockets, websocket

I am trying to create a realtime application in PHP using websockets. I had referred [this](https://phppot.com/php/simple-php-chat-using-websocket/) article . I am able to run this application on localhost but not in aws server.  I am getting this error

> (index):57 WebSocket connection to 'ws://52.187.147.178:8090/socket/php-socket.php' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

You may also check [this](http://13.229.251.124/socket/) link where i am facing error

Comment: Have you checked the port is not blocked by firewall?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Thanks for your reply. No, I haven't checked it yet. Will do that.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone is there any way through command line we can check if the port is blocked by firewall ?